# How to solve a ratio between radiuses of the attached diagram?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a red circle with a radius of 1. I'd like to get the exact ratio between it and the bigger blue circle radius. So how do you calculate AI/AJ in this case? I suppose it going to involve square root 3 anyway, but I can't get an idea, how to "mathematize" this diagram.

[image]

Comment: Assuming that all the black circles are congruent to the red circle, I guess?

Comment: ^ I believe so. @Casteels

Comment: Yes, and they are intersecting each other from the center of circles.

Comment: You are right, corrected word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AH}&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}+2\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1/2\\\sqrt3/2\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}2\\\sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
and since $|\overrightarrow{AH}|=\sqrt 7$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AJ}&=\overrightarrow{AH}+\frac{\overrightarrow{AH}}{|\overrightarrow{AH}|}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}2+2/\sqrt 7\\\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}/\sqrt{7}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
which has squared length
$$
\begin{align}
|\overrightarrow{AJ}|^2&=4+4/7+8/\sqrt{7}+3+3/7+6/\sqrt 7\\
&=8+14/\sqrt{7}
\end{align}
$$
And $14/\sqrt 7=14\sqrt7/7=2\sqrt 7$. Then just take the square root of that to get
$$
|\overrightarrow{AJ}|=\sqrt{8+2\sqrt 7}\approx 3.6458
$$

---

The ratio you were asking for is then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{|\overrightarrow{AI}|}{|\overrightarrow{AJ}|}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt 7}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt 7}}{8+2\sqrt 7}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt 7}(8-2\sqrt 7)}{36}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{8+2\sqrt 7}(4-\sqrt 7)}{18}\\
&\approx 0.274291885177431765
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Now it came clear: sqrt(2^2 + sqrt(3)^2) -> sqrt7. I totally missed that part. Thanks.